# How to compare local files from files on the main branch on bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to copmare files which are on my computer with files on the main branch of git. Do I need just download files from git and with certain command compare them?
After that I want to push my changes on the another branch "feature/add_button_component" on bitbucket. How it is better to do and what commands do I need?

Comment: How did the files end up on your computer? Have you cloned the repository and made some changes to them?

Comment: I wrote code and pushed it on the main page of bitbucket. After that I wrote another parts of code and accidantly git was deleted from my folder. So that I dont know how to compare changes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming .git folder was removed from your local repository.

1. Obtain the clone URL from Bitbucket;
2. Run `git clone <CLONE_URL> <ANOTHER_DIRECTORY>`;
3. Copy over the updated files from <OLD_DIRECTORY> to <ANOTHER_DIRECTORY>;
4. Switch to <ANOTHER_DIRECTORY> `cd <ANOTHER_DIRECTORY>`
5. Run `git diff` to compare your local changes to what you have in the main branch;
6. Run `git switch -c "feature/add_button_component"` to create the feature branch;
7. Add your changes with `git add -u`, commit with `git commit` and push with `git push`.

This might not be the most elegant, but should be the easiest option.

Comment: For example 
1) git clone git@bitbucket.org:fydor76/projectreactfront.git < some folder in my PC>
2) I copy my updated files and put them in the folder with clone from bitbucket
3) write git diff
write?

Comment: Write git diff in the command line after switching to the directory where the newly cloned repo resides. I've updated my answer.